# android checkbox drawable crashing app

Tags: android, checkbox

i'm kinda new to android and i am following other questions and answers on stack overflow and i feel like i am getting close, But i can't get it to work. 
when i tried it crashes my app.

just to test it's functionality i am using

[image]

and

[image: Image Checked]

and my code has a cb_selector in a drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked"
        android:color="#000000" />
    <!-- checked -->
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_empty"
        android:color="#000000"/>
    <!-- unchecked -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="#000000"/>
    <!-- on focus -->
    <item android:color="#000000"/>
    <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and my checkbox is:

```
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ownit_text"
        android:id="@+id/switch_ownit"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView_amiibo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_amiibo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_amiiboName"
        android:background="@drawable/cb_selector"/>
```

on the android ADK website it uses `android:textColor=""` and `android:background=""` on stack overflow someone has said to use `android:button=""`

when i use background or button it crashes. and when i use textcolor it just affects the checkboxes label and does not change the drawable.

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat

Comment: http://www.pastebin.ca/3029522 stack trace is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the log

> Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #15:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Change on your checkbox

```
 android:background="@drawable/cb_selector"/>
```

for

```
 android:button="@drawable/cb_selector"/>
```

Edit:

You are right you are using images so you have to change it for

```
 android:button="@drawable/cb_selector"/>
```

Be careful with the img size.

Also you need to delete the colors in the selector.xml and use a drawable for each state. Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked"
    />
    <!-- checked -->
    <item
    android:state_checked="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_empty"
   />
    <!-- unchecked -->
    <item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_empty"/>
    <!-- on focus -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_empty"/>
    <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: now it doesn't crash anymore, but it doesn't load the new image, it is remaining as the default android checkbox. and the color isn't changing either.

Comment: Edited, wasn't thinking about img

Comment: thanks. once i got rid of the color tags it worked fine.